# How to pass a struct to linux device node in python?

Tags: python, linux, struct, driver

There is a fpga device node in my /dev/. To communicate with its driver, I need to use the following C code.

```
struct pci_cmd {
    unsigned int bar_id;
    unsigned int command;
    void *device_addr;
    void *user_addr;
};

ssize_t f = open ("/dev/de4", O_RDWR);
unsigned short val;
struct pci_cmd read_cmd = { 0, 0, 0x2, &val };
read (f, &read_cmd, sizeof(val));
```

I found that there is struct class in python, but the `os.read(fd, n)` only accept two arguments. Any idea to do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use termios library of python to communicate if device node is tty I/O.
Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/termios.html

Also, You could use os.popen() or os.system() and directly write the system command.

Comment: It's not a tty I/O. It's a character device. The problem is the device driver need the struct pci_cmd information.